# Formato Fecha PhpSpreadSheet

Tags: php, date, phpspreadsheet

Tengo un archivo Excel con varios campos, entre ellos un campo de tipo fecha. Estoy usando PhpSpreadSheet para leer las celdas del excel y cargarlas en una consulta pero me he dado cuenta que al momento de leer la celda que contiene una fecha, la lee como numero, por ejemplo en el excel tengo 06/01/2018 y php lo devuelve como 43106. ¿Alguna idea de como leer como tal el 06/01/2018 o como convertir el numero entero?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el formato correcto, utiliza esta función propia de PhpSpreadSheet  que retornará un objeto DateTime.

```
$excelTimestamp = 43106; //valor recogido de la celda del archivo excel
$objetoDateTime = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($excelTimestamp);
```